# I need to pass an exception from async background task to main thread non async method

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, .net-4.5

I have an async task that runs in background. This task sends messages to apache kafka server. Whenever there is an problem with the network this results in exception. However the main thread is not able to catch this exception.

This is the code I used in background thread task -

```
async SendMessageAsync() {
 await Task.WhenAll(sendTasks.ToArray()).ContinueWith(e => e.Exception);
}
```

While my main thread non async method runs like -

```
try
{
Message[] messages = { new Message(msg) };
var res = _KafkaProducer.SendMessageAsync(topic, messages, acks, timeout, codec);
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
Console.WriteLine("Here");
}
```

The control never goes to Console.writeLine statement. If i implement task.wait() in the main thread then my main thread will block until my background thread finishes. Is there any other way to do this? I dont want to make the method on the main thread async.

Comment: So you want to wait asynchronously but not asynchronously. And you don't want to wait for the call to finish, but you want to wait for the call to finish to capture the Exception?

Comment: Why do you need to capture the Exception in the main thread? Could you maybe create a wrapper method that captures and handles the call instead? Or just capture and handle the exception in SendMessageAsync

Comment: I am looking for a way that doesn't require me to make the method on the main thread async and also to wait for the execution of the background thread to complete.

Comment: I need to bubble the exception up to my circuit breaker class. Thats why i want to capture it in the main thread.

Comment: Is this wrapper method going to be async? Can you provide code samples?

Comment: in main: `Task t = WrapAsync(); // dont wait` and in the wrapper add the whole `try catch` - I'm still not sure why you need to handle it in the main thread. Maybe the wrapper I suggest here wouldn't work either. You could also look into events, i.e. signal via en event if there was an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is currently using a "fire and forget" pattern, which is behaving correctly by ignoring any exceptions. If you don't want to ignore exceptions, then you shouldn't be using fire and forget.

Your options are (in order of preference):

1. `await` (making your main method `async`).
2. Block.
3. Notify. How exactly "notify" would work depends on the detains of how your main thread works (when and how it can receive signals).

> I need to bubble the exception up to my circuit breaker class.

So, applying the options above:

1. `await` (making your circuit breaker `async`-compatible).
2. Block.
3. Notify. But your main thread will have to *block waiting for notifications* before returning to the circuit breaker code.

Since the "notify" approach has been reduced to "block", it's no longer really tenable as a solution.

This leaves your only options as async or blocking.

I recommend `async`. It may be easier to [replace your circuit breaker with Polly's, which already has `async` support built-in](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly).